# Searching for NEC Code reference for service disconnect location

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance, nec, meter

I'm looking for the NEC code reference that allows a main panel within a home to contain a main breaker because the meter is directly on the other side of the outside wall, versus installing a meter-main outside.  I remember hearing something to the effect of no more than 5 feet of service cable between the two boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Article 230
>   Services**
>
> **VI. Service Equipment — Disconnecting Means
>   230.70 General**
>
> Means shall be provided to disconnect all conductors in a building or
>   other structure from the service-entrance conductors.
>
> **(A) Location.**
>
> The service disconnecting means shall be installed in accordance with
>   230.70(A)(1), (A)(2), and (A)(3).
>
> **(1) Readily Accessible Location.**
>
> The service disconnecting means shall be installed at a readily
>   accessible location either outside of a building or structure or
>   inside nearest the point of entrance of the service conductors.

Comment: That's all I was able to find too -- I have nary a clue where Kris is getting the 5' limit from, because it does not seem to be in the Code.  Perhaps it's an "inspector's rule of thumb"?

Comment: Notice that 230.70(A)(1) says "*inside nearest the point of entrance of the service conductors.*". The NEC does not give a specific length limit, though some local amendments might, and some service providers do as well (though utility specs are not enforceable by the local code enforcement authority) .

Comment: Exactly guys. This point has been contested forever. Some local inspectors use it to flex their muscle since it gives them the power to determine what *"nearest the point of entrance"* means.

Comment: The meaning seems plain enough: don't make that run any longer than it has to be.

Answer (score 1):

In Canada, the provincial Inspection Authorities issue Bulletins that put specific allowable lengths on the distance service conductors in conduit may run inside a building. So the precise distance varies with the jurisdiction, anywhere from 1.5m (59") to 6m (20'). The reason you can't find any mention in the NEC is probably similar.